# jQuery selectors in an object - reduce redundancy versus readability

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dry, readability

Let's say I have a web form that collects a company name and its address information from a user.  In a related javascript file, to reduce the jQuery selectors scattered throughout the functions and to collect related information in a single object structure, I might store all that in one object like in this simple example:

```
var companyForm = {
    name: {
        inputField: $("#CompanyName"),
        isValid: function() {
            return IsNameValid(this.inputField.val());
        },
        labelField: $("#CompanyNameLabel")
    },
    address: {
        inputField: $("#Address"),
        isValid: function() {
            return IsAddressValid(this.inputField.val());
        },
        labelField: $("#AddressLabel")
    },
    city: {
        inputField: $("#City"),
        isValid: function() {
            return IsCityValid(this.inputField.val());
        },
        labelField: $("#CityLabel")
    }
};
```

I only need to list these selectors once, and then whenever I need to reference the company name that the user entered, I can use this:

```
companyForm.name.inputField.val()
```

Or, if I want to check the validity of the user's input:

```
companyForm.name.isValid()
```

Etc.  (The labelField would be, say, a label element that I might want to add a class named "error" to, should the user enter badly formatted input and I want to emphasize to them that it needs their attention).

**My dilemma is, by applying the DRY principle to my jQuery selectors, I'm now hurting readability**, since:

```
$("#CompanyName").val()
```

is a lot easier to read and understand than:

```
companyForm.name.inputField.val()
```

**Should I not be trying to reduce redundancy in this manner?  Is there a better way I can manage or minimize the selector references?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about implementing getter and setter functions? that way you'd only call `companyForm.getName()` to get the value of `companyForm.name.inputField.val()`

Let's say:

```
var companyForm = {
    name: {
        inputField: $("#CompanyName"),
        isValid: function() {
            return IsNameValid(this.inputField.val());
        },
        labelField: $("#CompanyNameLabel")
    },
    ...
    getName: function() {
        return this.name.inputField.val();
   }
};
```

Comment: So simple a solution that I completely overlooked it!  And should I need access to the other various jQuery properties and functions linked to the underlying HTML input element, I can still reference them using the longer syntax.  Thanks!